@IdGeneratorType with OnExecutionGenerator
Is it possible to use generator that implements OnExecutionGenerator with the @IdGeneratorType meta-annotation? It seems like I am missing some type of configuration, because hibernate generates the right SQL for inserts, but does not create the right DDL for my table.
I have my custom generator that extends IdentityGenerator which implements OnExecutionGenerator:
public class MyIdGeneratorImpl extends IdentityGenerator {}

Then the generator is used with @IdGeneratorType
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD})
@IdGeneratorType(MyIdGeneratorImpl.class)
public @interface MyIdGenerator{}

Finally @IdGeneratorType is applied to abstract root entity Id column.
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
  @Id
  @MyIdGenerator
  @Column(name = "Id")
  private Long id;
}

Generated hibernate DDL:
Hibernate: 
    create table MY_TABLE(
        Column_1 numeric(22,10),
        Column_2 numeric(22,10),
        Id bigint not null,
        primary key (ID_)
    )

Generated hibernate SQL insert:
insert into MY_TABLE (Column_1,Column_2,Id) values (?,?,default)

This insert causes NULL not allowed for column Id constraint violation. My question is, why is Id not marked as bigint generated by default as identity, as it is when using GenericGenerator with native strategy instead of @IdGeneratorType?

Since you are using a customized id generator, Hibernate can't interpolate all the characteristics you need on the database schema to match the generator logic.
You need to specify in the @Column annotation the additional informations that have to be used in DDL, like this:
@Id
@MyIdGenerator
@Column(name = "Id", columnDefinition = "bigint generated by default as identity")
private Long id;

Like it's done in Using BigInteger as primary key in Spring JPA gives - Incorrect column specifier for column 'id'

Thank you, although this does work on the example I provided, it fails on slightly more complicated case. When I have a foreign key, which references id of a class that also inherits from AbstractEntity, hibernate marks the foreign key as generated as well: I get create table MY_TABLE(Id_ bigint generated by default as identity, Foreign_key bigint generated by default as identity) which is not the thing I would want.

I see, actually the columnDefinition is propagated each time that column is referenced in other entities. A (very ugly) solution may be to define, for each joinColumn  used in the references a columnDefinition = "bigint", but it would be better to find how to trigger, for the annotated id, the additional informations of the custom value generation. I will try to find out something...
